# Replace a String containing a "

Tags: vb.net

I have run into a problem trying to get this code to work:

```
filereader.Replace(Chr(34) & "SomeSetting" & Chr(34) & "=dword:00000000", Chr(34) & "SomeSetting" & Chr(34) & "=dword:00000001")
```

I want it to replace a string which is !exaclty! looking like this, containing the quotation marks:

"SomeSetting"=dword:00000000

but what it does is looking for this string:

""SomeSetting""=dword:00000000

and i cant get it to work. Even if i tried this:

```
Dim Test As String = Chr(34)
```

Test will look like this:
""
instead of "
 what am i missing here?

Comment: You are missing that 00000000 does not match 00000001

Comment: You should never use `Chr(34)`. Even if it works, it's cryptic. Use `ControlChars.Quote` or just use a literal double-quote, which is represented simply by escaping it with another double-quote, e.g. `"He said " & ControlChars.Quote & "Hello" & ControlChars.Quote & " to me"` can be replaced with `"He said ""Hello"" to me"`.

Comment: Reading your question again, I see that you're wring about the issue. It's not looking for what you think it is. That's simply how the debugger is representing it to you, i.e. where there is a literal double-quote in the text, it's being represented with an escaped double-quote. It's not looking for two double-quotes. It's simply showing you two double-quotes because that's how a literal double-quote is represented.

Comment: So according to you     Dim Test As String = """SomeSetting""" should yield the value "SomeSetting" for Test, but it will result in ""SomeSetting"" (all the quotation makrs are contained in the string in this example so the values are looking exaclty like that, in the debugger its shwon as a """SomeSetting""")

Comment: filereader.Replace("""SomeSetting""=dword:00000001", """SomeSetting""=dword:00000000") will not work either

Comment: What **EXACTLY** does the original `String` look like in the Watch window?

Comment: The String looks exactly like this in the watch window: ""SomeSetting"=dword:00000000"

Comment: As already noted you have to differentiate between the debugger's display and the final output. The debugger will display `""SomeSetting""=dword:00000000`, but if you showed the string in a message box: `MessageBox.Show(Chr(34) & "SomeSetting" & Chr(34) & "=dword:00000000")` it would display: `"SomeSetting"=dword:00000000`. What the debugger shows is not necessarily the same as the final output.

Comment: Thanks vincent, I see whats happening there, but for some odd reason it just wont replace that string then even though i apparently i did it correct in the first place. Any idea what could cause that? im using writealllines(filename, filereader,true) to save the changes. but if im monitoring the filereader string i even see that it wont change that part of that string (debugger)

Comment: I just realized the problem. The lack of context (where this code is located, if there is any other code around it or whether this is exactly what your line looks like) made it hard to see where the problem was. See my answer below for more info.

Comment: Thank your for the advice, next time i ask something, i will provide more code.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem... This is a quite common, accidental thing for people to do.

Strings are immutable, which means that once you've created them they cannot be changed without creating a new string instance.

The problem is this:

```
filereader.Replace(Chr(34) & "SomeSetting" & Chr(34) & "=dword:00000000", Chr(34) & "SomeSetting" & Chr(34) & "=dword:00000001")
```

The [**`Replace()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) ***returns the new string*** with the replaced value(s) (since it cannot change the original one), but you ***never use*** the instance it returns.

You should set your old string variable to the new string returned by `Replace()`, like this:

```
filereader = filereader.Replace(Chr(34) & "SomeSetting" & Chr(34) & "=dword:00000000", Chr(34) & "SomeSetting" & Chr(34) & "=dword:00000001")
```

---

***To avoid*** (or at least minimize the risk of) things like this happening, make sure you read the information that Visual Studio's IntelliSense shows you when writing the function call.

If you do bump into problems anyway, make sure to check the MSDN documentation to see if you missed anything. They usually also have examples showing how you can use the methods.